I scraped web using `rvest` and stored the result of read_html() in a list object. I closed Rstudio and when I reopen and try to load, get an error
This is what I did:
library(rvest)

list[[i]] <- read_html(link)

save(list, path = "path.Rdata")

Then I closed and reopened the environment.
load("path.Rdata")

list[[i]]

`Error in doc_type(x) : external pointer is not valid`

Can anyone explain the problem here? How can I solve it?
Saving tens of thousands of HTMLs took almost a day from me. I prefer a solution that uses the current local files.
I actually don't know what to do now!

Some R objects are "non-exportable" to .rds and presumably to .Rdata files.
See these previous questions and their answers:
link1 and link2
